# How can I send a html entities text via GET method in PHP?

Tags: php, html, get

I sent a text via GET method to decode html entities   `( &#119; = w  )`

```
> ?text=&#119;&type=htmldecode&format=text
```

I got errors in the $text variable then I tried to set it in the last of the link

```
?format=text&type=htmldecode&text=&#119;
```

and I got the same errors

how I can fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of encoding pertinent to your problem. [HTML escape characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php), and [URL escape chars](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).

When you have a character in an HTML page, you use the HTML escape characters. eg

`&#119; = w`

But you cannot use those characters in a URL - `&` and `#` have special meanings in URLs. So you have to encode again - this time using URL escape characters.

`# = %23`

`& = %26`

`; = %3B`

So your string, ('w') fit to be put into a URL, would be:

`%23%26119%3B`

and your entire query string:

`?text=%23%26119%3B&type=htmldecode&format=text`

the aforementioned PHP urlencode() does this.

The snippet:

```
<?php echo urlencode("&#119;"); ?>
```

outputs

`%26%23119%3B`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to decode it then re-encode it using URL encoding [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode)